# How to add values in two tables having Relation using single form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I m new at Laravel, I want to add data in two tables using single form. My table and their relation are

[image]

I want to add all the fields for user then select the class_id and then section_id through dropdown.

And then register and I want that after data is registered . The Registration table should have user_id of that new user registered and selected class and section id.

Fields for **Student Table**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('/storeStudent')}}">
@csrf

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

        @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif
    </div>
    </div>


     <input id="role_id" type="hidden" name="role_id" value="2">
```

Fields Starting for **Registration Table**

```
    <select class="" name="class_id">
         <option value="null">Class</option>
         @foreach($cid as $cc)
             @if($counterr==0)
                 <option selected="selected" value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
                 {{$counterr++}}
             @else

                 <option value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
             @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>

     <select section="" name="section_id">
         <option value="null">Section</option>
         @foreach($sec as $sc)
             @if($counterrr==0)
                 <option selected="selected" value="{{$sc->id}}">{{$sc->title}}</option>
                 {{$counterrr++}}
             @else

                 <option value="{{$sc->id}}">{{$sc->title}}</option>
             @endif
         @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

**Registration Controller**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Registration::create([
            'reg_id' => $data['reg_id'],
            'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
            'class_id' => $data['class_id'],
            'section_id' => $data['section_id'],


        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        registration::create($request->all());

        return back();
    }
```

**Store Student**

```
    public function storeStudent(Request $request)
{
    $user=new User();
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->password=Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->role_id=2;
    $user->parent_id=$request->parent_id;
    $user->save();


    return back();
}
```

Now I want that same user_id which is going to be registered should also be saved in **Registration Table**

I have used simple store method in controller for saving data.

Comment: Please paste your controller method.

Comment: I have updated the controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy..your should get created User and use it's id...something like this:

**Student Controller:**

```
public function storeStudent(Request $request)
{
     $created_user = User::create([
         'name' => $request->name,
         'email' => $request->email,
         'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
         'parent_id' => $request->parent_id,
         'role_id' => $request->role_id,
     ]);

     //And after that you need to store user_id in Registration table , so:

     Registration::create([
         'user_id' => $created_user->id,
         'class_id' => $request->class_id,
         'section_id' => $request->section_id,
     ]);

     return redirect()->back();

}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I didn't imagined that it was so simple.. Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link. You might get some ideas regarding relationship in laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

If this does not help then I need to see your controller and model. Please paste your controller and model code.

Comment: I have made relationship between these I m having issues with syntax

Comment: You might have got some error if your syntax is wrong. What does the error say? Please write the error. Also provide migration of user, registration and model of user, registration

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the new user_id  on which work is to be done and to be saved in registration controller

Comment: You should first create user and then use the created user id in your registration.

Comment: If user is allowed only to register after login then you can use auth()->user()->id in user_id of registration